# Returning SolrDocument object with cxf web service

Tags: solr, cxf

We are developing a search application. All of the stuff is done, like SOLR schema, search queries, faceted search etc. I tried to develop a cxf web service that returns a list of SolrDocument. Everything is OK until I try to make the return type of the service function as SolrDocument. I know that CXF does not generate return types for java objects that does not have an empty constructor. For SolrDocument object is this the case? Besides, I succeeded to return complex java object types with CXF. For returning SolrDocument as an object what is your proposed solutions?

An idea that came to my mind was to create my own Document object and convert SolrDocument to that type but it is expensive since I already have the search results as SolrDocument.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. The problem is related with SolrDocumentList. Since SolrDocumentList Class is not serializable CXF can not make the mappings. The solutions is to create your bean. For example we have an VODItem.Class compatible with the fields defined in the Solr schema, then while searching we have to do:

```
DocumentObjectBinder binder = new DocumentObjectBinder();
List<VodItem> vodResults = new ArrayList<VodItem>();
vodResults = binder.getBeans(VodItem.class, SolrDocumentList);
```

Now web service can do the neccessary mappings.